# How to execute code written in an editor embedded within a browser

Tags: c++

Hi Guys I was writing a web application which requires me to compile and execute code from within a browser. I am a little clueless about it though I read the following links to see how I can go about it.

http://www.quora.com/Interviewstreet/How-can-I-build-a-compiler-like-the-one-on-InterviewStreet-from-scratch

http://norvig.com/lispy.html

developer.hackerearth.com

I am planning to write it for several languages namely C/C++/java/python/Ruby

Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Take a look at [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: Another way is to just take the source code and [convert it to JavaScript](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/03/cpp-to-javascript).

Comment: I wish to write code on the editor provided by my web application. In that case how do I use ideone-is there an exposed API that I can use to send code to a sandbox where it can be compiled and the results can be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the code and send it to server server will compile and execute the code and send back to the browser.

If you don't have much time.

If you have much time then you can build your own compiler like one you want and integrate it with you'r web application. like w3school and ideone.

or pass it to local host compiler it will execute and return the result to the browser.